# where's the Gemfile in a rails 1 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Where's the Gemfile located in a rails version 1 application?

I looked in the root of the app, it has Rakefile but not Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

try searching for "gemfile" from your root folder. I have never used rails 1 before, so no idea!

Comment: find | grep Gemfile   reveals nothing )-: